# Extension DOM is required. Symfony project doesn't start

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I'm turning php7.0.27, but there's a problem when starting my symfony project (when doing `php bin/console server:run`).

I receive this error:

> Extension DOM is required.

I tried to resolve it by:

- `sudo apt-get install php-xml`
- `php -i | grep simplexml`
- `sudo composer require ext-simplexml`

But all those comands didn't work, nothing changed.

Always error :

> In XmlUtils.php line 50: Extension DOM is required.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just a thought. Did you try $ sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml ? Try that and see if the xml extension is loaded when you type $ php -m

Comment: hello Andreas Tanks

I tried it but receiving the error package php7.0-xml unreachable

And when typing the second command, xml not enable